# Handling routes in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an action that I want to use to handle the saving of a report for a project and a sub project.  The code to run is essentially the same so I thought I could create a custom save action and then specify the routes; however, it doesn't seem to be working as expected.

My action signature is

```
[Route("Project/{projectNumber}/Reports/ProjectHoursAndCosts/save")]
[Route("Project/{projectNumber}/Reports/ProjectHoursAndCosts/{subProjectNumber}/save")]
public ActionResult ProjectHoursAndCosts(ProjectHoursAndCostsViewModel projectHoursAndCostsViewModel)
```

If I remove one of the routes it works as expected.  Any ideas?

I've set the action in form

```
(Html.BeginForm("Save", "Reports"))
```

If my initial url is

```
http://somehost/somewebapp/Project/61033651/Reports/ProjectHoursAndCosts
```

it seems to work ok, however if I try to save a sub project which has the url

```
http://somehost/somewebapp/Project/61033651/Reports/ProjectHoursAndCosts/61033651-1
```

When I hit save the url changes back to

```
http://somehost/somewebapp/Project/61033651/Reports/ProjectHoursAndCosts/save
```

I would expect it to submit to the url

```
http://somehost/somewebapp/Project/61033651/Reports/ProjectHoursAndCosts/61033651-1/save
```

### Update

Looking at the raw form element in the html page I can see that even though the url is `http://somehost/somewebapp/Project/61033651/Reports/ProjectHoursAndCosts/61033651-1`, the actual post url is still `somewebapp/Project/61033651/Reports/ProjectHoursAndCosts/save`

How can I change the action attribute of the form to use the correct url?

Comment: What is not _working as expected_ - what do you expect and what is actually happening? And how are you calling the method

Comment: Add the `Order` property - `[Route("Project/{projectNumber}/Reports/ProjectHoursAndCosts/save", Order = 2)]` and `Order = 1` for the 2nd